How do I make rails exception_handler gem "verbose"?
I am building a rails CRUD app. I have installed the exception_handler gem and it works well enough. However I would like it to give more info in the browser.
For example, trying to create a new record with missing info might show:
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (Validation failed: Title can't be blank):

in the console, but the response in the browser is just:
"Unprocessable Entity"

which is a bit unhelpful. How can I get the actual error back to the user?
This database will never be used by general public - it is for my own use. I am just looking for a way to provide feedback about what schema rule was broken in the easiest way, without needing to code a response for every possible case. I chose to raise an exception as I thought that it might help to make that happen - the exception contains helpful info about what went wrong. I just need to get that info into the browser.
CODE SAMPLE:
schema:
  create_table "recordings", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title", null: false
    t.string "isrc"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

model:
class Recording < ApplicationRecord 
    validates_presence_of :title
    validates :isrc, uniqueness: true
end

controller:
    def new
        @recording = Recording.new
    end

    def create
        @recording = Recording.create!(recording_params)
        redirect_to recording_path(@recording)
    end

view:
<%= form_for @recording do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :title %>: <%= f.text_field "title" %><br>
    <%= f.label :isrc %>: <%= f.text_field "isrc" %><br>
    <%= f.label :work_id %>: <%= f.collection_select :work_id, Work.order(:title), :id, :title %><br>
    <%= f.label "artist" %>: <%= f.collection_select :person_id, Person.order(:name), :id, :name %><br>
    <%= f.label "audio file" %>: <%= f.file_field :audio_file %><br>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>


Please provide more info: router, controller with action, view

why are you raising on a validation error?

I don't use this gem. But default Rails error page is definitely quite verbose in dev: https://i.sstatic.net/s9em8.png If you are requesting JSON or Turbo Stream, then the error is mostly in your browser console. Though in general when there is a validation error on the model such as "Title can"t be blank" you usually don't show an error message, but rather re render the new or edit view for the user to change the input data..

@AntonBogdanov - done

@Alex - please see remarks in updated post above.

@Maxence - indeed, if I don't use Exception Handler, that is just what happens, but with no feedback t the user (because it is not in the view of course)

@danmcb I am not sure I get it. You are raising because you use create with a bang Recording.create!(recording_params) you should instead create without a bang. then if any error happens in validation, they will be attached to the record you are trying to create. Then when you redirect to :new or :edit, you can catch these errors and display them. Just run a simple scaffold rails g scaffold MyModel and check the files created, especially the views, you will see the errors are dealt with by default. You can migrate then rails db:rollback step=1 to revert changes to db.

the exception contains helpful info about what went wrong - use Recording.create method, @recording.errors will have the validation error info, just render it on a page, i'd say exception_handler is doing more harm than good here. besides, default rails scaffold already does a basic crud if that's all you need.

ok! thank you Alex / Maxence - I will try. Still finding my way with rails a bit. cheers
